# React Routing: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I recently updated the routing from v5 to v6, I've looked at the answers here and tried to implement the solutions as best I could when upgrading from v5 to v6. I think the problem stems from my protected route component.

I don't get why it allowed me to login in and then suddenly the browser can't find the user that I logged in with. The user is in the database and I Can login just fine from the backend with insomnia.

This is the v5 version

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
 
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user.isAuthenticated && !user.pending) navigate("/");
  });

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (user.isAuthenticated && !user.pending) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else return <LoadingScreen />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

V6

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import LoadingScreen from "../components/LoadingScreen";

const ProtectedRoute = ({children}) => {
  const {isAuthenticated, pending} = useSelector((state) => state.user);
 
  if (pending) return null;
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to= "/" replace />
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Routes in App.js

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadUser(Store.dispatch);
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Alert />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/board"
          element={<ProtectedRoute><Boards /></ProtectedRoute>}
        />
        <Route
          path="/board/:id"
          element={<ProtectedRoute><Board /></ProtectedRoute>}
        />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={<FreeRoute><Login /></FreeRoute>}
        />
        <Route
          path="/register"
          element={<FreeRoute><Register /></FreeRoute>}
        />
        <Route path="/" element={<FreeRoute><Index /></FreeRoute>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: This is a server issue, as in *how* the server is handling page requests and serving the React app. How are you running the app produce this issue? The gist is that the server should return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app so that the React app loads and handles matching the appropriate route internally. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather a sense of what might need to be configured for your specific case.

Comment: Sorry, I feel I misunderstood your post. Are you trying access any specific page and get a 404 for the page from the server, or is this some other request that is returned a 404? What exactly are you doing, and what exactly is the issue? Can you [edit] with clearer details, the complete error message and code stacktrace if available, and a more complete [mcve] of the frontend code, and possibly your backend code processing it if that's code you maintain?

Comment: Ah sorry, issue started when I just changed the localhost port from 3000 to 3030 to match my backend, but I reverted those changes and All I get is a white screen now. I'm trying to convert that code above (v5)  to (v6) but don't know how to go about it. I've looked at other solutions but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Is this a backend that is hosting/serving the frontent app? Or you are just using a local development server and the backend is hosting the backend APIs? Or both? Something else?

Comment: react is hosting the frontend, backend is both

Comment: I just want the v5 converted to v6 so hopefully I can just get the this app to show something at all

Comment: The "v6" code looks fine to me. I don't see any overt issues.

Comment: Thats the thing, I thought so too but it just doesn't display anything at all, the screen is just white, so its definitely my v6 version, it just doesnt display any errors on the console, unlike the v5 code

Comment: What "resource" was requested that is returning a 404? That's not a `react-router-dom` thing. Are there any other errors in the network tab or in the console?

Comment: No errors at all, the resource requested was a User that I logged in with, It can retrieve the user in the console but the screen is still white despite the fact that the user is logged in and won't retrieve any of the boards that the user has.

Comment: That's a separate issue to rendering content it seems. Try removing that call and update the routes to render some test UI, e.g. `<Route path="/" element={<h1>Test</h1>} />`. If possible, can you try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the rendering issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/autumn-cdn-l44so2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I'm not sure how to link the code sandbox I think I just link it, Its my first time using it, sorry about that

Comment: The link is fine, I got to the sandbox. The sandbox is incomplete though, missing at least the `src/components/pages` directory. Did you ensure saving all files?